# Cannot add child of child to XML element

Tags: php, xml

I am building some server-side functions for an app I am making.

I have a piece of code that's causing me bother.

It is supposed to add some children to the child of an element in an XML document. Instead, it replaces the entire file with the new information and I cannot work out why.

PHP:

```
function addRole($pid, $id, $name){
    echo $pid;
    $xml = self::getXml();

    foreach($xml->children() as $project){
        if($project->id == $pid){
            echo self::toJSON($project->roles);
            $roles = $project->roles->children();
            echo self::toJSON($roles);
            $role = $roles->addchild("role");
            $role->addChild("id", $id);
            $role->addChild("name", $name);
            echo self::toJSON($role);
            $role->asXml("../data/projects.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file should look like this (this is a sample of the actual XML from `projects.xml`):

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <id>adultScotland</id>
        <name>Adults(Scotland)</name>
        <roles>
            <role>
                <id>projectM</id>
                <name>Project Manager</name>
            </role>
        </roles>
       <courses>
           <course>Administration of Medication</course>
           <course>Infection Control</course>
           <course>Introducing Positive Approaches to Behaviour</course>
       </courses>
    </project>
</projects>
```

What have I done wrong?

Should anybody want to look at it, getXML() is this:

```
function getXml(){
     $xml=simplexml_load_file("../data/projects.xml") or die("ERROR: Unable to read file");
return $xml;
}
```

Comment: You overwrite the original file with the `role` node, `$role->asXml("../data/projects.xml");` instead of the document.

Comment: ... instead of `$xml->asXML(...)`

Comment: @michi which should be _after_ the `foreach` loop. (Just in case they expect to just c+p that in-place.)

Comment: okay, so that stops the function from overwriting the file, but it's putting the   new `role`'s inside the already existing role... thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your question. You should change your foreach loop with my example. I've deleted everything that wasn't necessary for my experiment.

```
foreach($xml->children() as $project){
    if($project->id == $pid){
        $roles = $project->roles;
        $role = $roles->addchild("role");
        $role->addChild("id", $id);
        $role->addChild("name", $name);
    }
}
$xml->asXML('your_xml_doc_name.xml');
```

Problem was in your code: `$roles = $project->roles->children();`. With it you accessed role itself, but you have to access children of roles. In simplexml it can be done like `$roles = $project->roles;`.
Basic simplexml usage documentation http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Next proble was in asXML function. You need to save whole document, not just new role. So instead of `$role->asXml("../data/projects.xml");' in foreach loop, you should print after`$xml->asXML('your_xml_doc_name.xml');`. 
asXML function documentation http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `<roles>`node without `foreach()` by `xpath()` in one line of code:

```
$roles = $xml->xpath("/projects/project[id = 'dummy']/roles")[0];
```

The above statement will...

- select all `<project>`having the child `<id>` as `dummy` (hopefully, this is only 1  node)
- return its `<roles>` node including all children as a `SimpleXML element`
- stored in an array `$roles`
- by `[0]` we reference the first element only in that array (requires PHP >= 5.4)

`$xml` of course is a SimpleXML object.

Then, you can add the new `<role>` as above:

```
$newrole = $roles->addchild("role");
// etc.
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/434484